# Compiling the same assembly with different names

Tags: c#, compilation, .net-assembly

I have a C# winform application that is compiled twice.

First time to run in FULL SCREEN mode
Second time to run in normal size mode; within the size of the winform.

Currently each compilation is in its own folder.

What I need is to compile these 2 versions into one/same folder. So the files GUI.exe and GUI-FULL_SCREEN.exe would be in the same folder.

What I've tried:

- first I compiled normal mode application with assembly name as GUI.exe
- then I changed the assembly name to GUI-FULL_SCREEN.exe (in Application properties/Application/Assembly name) and compiled it into the same directory. This removed the first assembly GUI.exe and created new one GUI-FULL_SCREEN.exe instead.

What I want to achieve is that GUI.exe and GUI-FULL_SCREEN.exe would stay in the same directory.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you use MsBuild ? Do you want this to happen only on your development PC ?

Comment: I develop and compile in Visual Studio 2010. I compile/release on my dev PC. Yes I guess VS 2010 uses MSBuild

Comment: Ok, what is different in the two builds ? Do you build once, then update the code to run in full screen and build again ? (mainly how do you change this setting)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I do. I have a variable bool showFullScreen = true/false. Based on this variable application runs in full/normal screen size mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use command line arguments to switch this setting and create just a shortcut instead of a new exe file.

For example if *fullscreen* is passed start the app as full screen, otherwise in normal mode.
You could use [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx) to get the arguments.

Then just create a shortcut to your exe file, call it GUI-FULL_SCREEN and start the app with the required parameter: *'".\GUI.exe" /fullscreen'*